# My external js file wont load?

Tags: javascript, html

The Javascript file is not loading at all in my website. I have checked the whole file for errors, but couldn't find any. I have also tried other javascript files which did work. I am pretty sure that there is an error but cant find it. Also if you know a more efficient way to do my code please tell me. I already went from 1.3k lines to 300 lines :/

Javascript: http://pastebin.com/YJNSvDnP

Html:

```
<script src="script/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/Klikfunctie.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: Check the devtools network tab.

Comment: You proberly have an error in your Klikfunctie.js, therefor it will not load if it can't compile, press F12 in your browser to see if you get an error msg.

Comment: Can you share your project folder structure please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error on console :

```
SyntaxError: missing formal parameter


function ChangeColors(var a, var b, var c, var d){
```

Change `function ChangeColors(var a, var b, var c, var d)` to function `ChangeColors(a,  b,  c,  d)`